# Is this equation $\nabla_a\sqrt{-g}=0$ correct?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Is the equation
$$\nabla_a\sqrt{-g}=0$$
correct? Here $\nabla_a$ is the Levi-Civita connection, and $g$ is the determinant of metric $g_{ab}$. Apparently, we have $\nabla_ag_{bc}=0$, but I am not sure whether the up-mentioned equation is correct or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249961/2451

Answer (score 2):

The square root of the determinant of the metric can be understood as a particular function of the components of the metric $g_{ab}$ $$\sqrt{-g} =f(g_{ab})$$
By the chain rule we of course have
$$\nabla_a \sqrt{-g} = \nabla_a f(g_{bc}) = \frac{df}{d g_{bc}} \nabla_a g_{bc}$$
But we know that $\nabla_a g_{bc}=0$ so that of course $\nabla_a \sqrt{-g} =0$. This result naturally applies to any function of $g_{ab}$ which does not involve its derivatives.

Comment: I know this argument, what I am not sure is that the chain rule is used properly. I mean, the $df/dg_{bc}$ is the ordinary derivative, while is different from the covariant derivative.