# Covariant derivative of a metric determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

The covariant derivative of a metric is zero $g_{\alpha\beta;\sigma}=0$. Is the covariant derivative of a metric determinant zero following the assumption($g_{\alpha\beta;\sigma}=0$):

$$
g_{;\sigma}=g g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\beta;\sigma}=0?
$$

In general, can the chain rule for ordinary derivative be used for the covariant derivative as

$$
F(f(x))_{;p}=F_{;p}f_{;p}?
$$

Or always replace the covariant derivative of a scalar with the ordinary derivative?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/249961/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Still have a question.